# Derive number till 2 decimal places from a decimal or float value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a requirement in which there is a column (decimal/float) having values ranging from integers (like 1) to numbers having upto 6 decimal places (like 1.123456). I want to get the values as explained in logic below.

```
 value1     |   value_new
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
13.123456   |   131234.56   --logic: value1: if there are 6 values after decimal, value_new: multiply value1 by 10000
0.12345     |   123.45      --logic: value1: if there are 5 values after decimal, value_new: multiply value1 by 1000
13.1234     |   1312.34     --logic: value1: if there are 4 values after decimal, value_new: multiply value1 by 100 
13.123      |   131.23      --logic: value1: if there are 3 values after decimal, value_new: multiply value1 by 10 
13.12       |   13.12
13.1        |   13.1
13          |   13
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Create table:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Value1 float
)

INSERT INTO @T (Value1) VALUES
(13.123456),
(0.12345),
(13.1234),
(13.123),
(13.12),
(13.1),
(13);
```

Comment: Is this a round or truncate operation? I mean, would `12.5678` be translated to `12.57` or to `12.56`?

Comment: So is the column `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT`? This makes quite a bit of difference. Also, why do you think casting to a `DECIMAL` with a scale of 2 is "not a viable solution"? Then there's also `ROUND`, and then there is (as always) the issue to consider that if you just want to *display* the values differently (rather than actually change the values themselves) this should preferably be left up to clients (as you force your numbers into strings that way).

Comment: If you are wanting to round this number to two decimal places then `Round()` is what you want. If `Round()` isn't what you are looking for then you'll need to explain why.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: there is no round operation used. Please see "remark".

Comment: @JeroenMostert : sorry i have asked the wrong question, earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This REALLY belongs in the presentation layer, however, one option is to create string via `format()`.

Please Note:  format() is not very performant.  It should be used sparingly.

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,NewValue = format(value1,'0.##')
 From  YourTable


value1      NewValue
13.123456   13.12
13.12345    13.12
13.1234     13.12
13.123      13.12
13.12       13.12
13.1        13.1
13          13
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

One way to get there is by using `cross apply` to calculate an int that's 1000000 bigger than the original float value, and then `%` to determine how may digits after the decimal separator there are in the original number - and a simple `case` expression:

```
SELECT  Value1, 
        CASE 
            WHEN Base % 10000 = 0 THEN Value1 
            WHEN Base % 1000 = 0 THEN Value1 * 10
            WHEN Base % 100 = 0 THEN Value1 * 100
            WHEN Base % 10 = 0 THEN Value1 * 1000
            ELSE Value1 * 10000
        END As NewValue
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST((Value1 * 1000000) AS INT) As Base
) baseValue
```

Results:

```
Value1      NewValue
13,123456   131234,56
13,12345    13123,45
13,1234     1312,34
13,123      131,23
13,12       13,12
13,1        13,1
13          13
```

---

**First version** (The question is now different)

Though I agree this is the presentation layer responsibility,
Another option is to multiply by 100, cast to int, cast back to float and divide by 100 again.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Value1 float
)

INSERT INTO @T (Value1) VALUES
(13.123456),
(13.12345),
(13.1234),
(13.123),
(13.12),
(13.1),
(13);
```

The query:

```
SELECT Value1, CAST(CAST(Value1 * 100 AS int) AS float) / 100 As NewValue
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Value1      NewValue
13,123456   13,12
13,12345    13,12
13,1234     13,12
13,123      13,12
13,12       13,12
13,1        13,1
13          13
```

Comment: your solution was working perfectly. But unfortunately i asked wrong question earlier. Corrected question now. :)

Comment: you're just GREAT. :D

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)